# How can I solve the "Method does not override any method from its superclass" error?

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I'm trying to make a kind of conditional segue through the "shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier" override function, and it reports the error "Method does not override any method from its superclass" and tells me to remove the "override" word. When I do so, it reports the next error:

> "Method 'shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(*:sender:)' with Objective-C selector 'shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:' conflicts with method 'shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(*:sender:)' from superclass 'UIViewController' with the same Objective-C selector".

This is my code now:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
//MARK: Propierties
@IBOutlet weak var whateverLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var errorMessageLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textFieldRandomWord: UITextField!
//MARK: Actions
@IBAction func printWhatever(sender: UIButton) {whateverLabel.text = "Whatever"
    }

@IBOutlet weak var goOnButton: UIButton!

 override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String, sender: UIButton?) -> Bool {
    if identifier == "firstsegue" && sender == goOnButton { // you define it in the storyboard (click on the segue, then Attributes' inspector > Identifier

        if textFieldRandomWord.text == "Whatever" {
            errorMessageLabel.textColor = UIColor .redColor()
            errorMessageLabel.text = "*** NOPE, segue wont occur"
            return false
        }
        else {
            errorMessageLabel.text = "*** YEP, segue will occur"
        }
    }

    // by default, transition
    return true
    }
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
textFieldRandomWord.delegate = self //ViewController is textFieldRandomWord's delegate, so "self" reffers to itself (ViewController)//
}
//MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
     func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
//Hide the keyboard.
    textFieldRandomWord.resignFirstResponder()
    return true}
func textFieldDidEndEditing(textField: UITextField){
   whateverLabel.text = textFieldRandomWord.text}
//Above, the textFieldShouldReturn function makes the text field inactive when return (enter) is pressed. The last function gets activated automatically when this happens.//
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`sender` should be `AnyObject?`. You can't change type in methods declaration to fit your current need like that. You have to check inside the function if your `sender` is `UIButton`.

Comment: But then how can I make the whole function be triggered by the button I want ("goOnButton")?

Comment: Can I make it through putting the function inside the action function of the button and deleting the "sender == goOnButton" part?

Comment: You can add IBAction method to you button which calls `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender` method. Then you should override `prepareForSegue:sender` method to prepare everything before segueing.

Comment: so, where should I exactly place the prepareForSegue method?

Comment: For example in your `printWhatever` method (I assume it is connected to your `goOnButton`)

Comment: So create IBAction for your goOnButton and inside it put `prepareForSegueWithIdentifier("firstSegue", sender: sender)`. `sender` is sender argument from your IBAction.

Comment: @IBAction func goOn(sender: UIButton) {
   override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String,sender: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
   if identifier == "firstsegue" { // you define it in the storyboard (click on the segue, then Attributes' inspector > Identifier
   if textFieldRandomWord.text == "Whatever" {
       errorMessageLabel.textColor = UIColor .redColor()
       errorMessageLabel.text = "*** NOPE, segue wont occur"
       return false
       }
       else {
       errorMessageLabel.text = "*** YEP, segue will occur"
     }}// by default, transition
       return true
       }}